# Gravity Forms Date Push Reservations

Tags: forms, date, gravity

I currently use GF for reservations 'Arrive' and 'Departure'.  I would like the date displayed on the 'Departure' to always be one date ahead of the 'Arrival' date, regards of what date the guest picks.  Then can pick a custom 'Departure' date, but as a default I'd like to show one date forward of the 'Arrival' date no matter what 'Arrival' date they choose.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with the [gform_datepicker_options_pre_init](https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_datepicker_options_pre_init/) JS filter. Example #3 is what you're after:

```
gform.addFilter( 'gform_datepicker_options_pre_init', function( optionsObj, formId, fieldId ) {
    if ( formId == 12 && fieldId == 8 ) {
        optionsObj.minDate = 0;
        optionsObj.onClose = function (dateText, inst) {
            jQuery('#input_12_9').datepicker('option', 'minDate', dateText).datepicker('setDate', dateText);
        };
    }
    return optionsObj;
});
```

If you're looking for a code-less solution, I've written a plugin that let's you do this in just a few clicks called [GP Limit Dates](http://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gp-limit-dates/).

Also, here is an article that addresses your specific need: [How to restrict dates in second date field based on date selected in first date field with Gravity Forms](http://gravitywiz.com/how-to-restrict-dates-in-second-date-field-based-on-date-selected-in-first-date-field-with-gravity-forms/)